# Custom http security configuration along with OAuth2 resource server

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using `Spring Security OAuth2` with a very basic configuration that is working fine. I now want to have a separate `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that contains custom logic that determines whether someone has authority to access some endpoints. However, it is not executed no matter what I try. Below are my `OAuth2` configurations and my findings on the topic. Authorization server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authentication -> authenticationManager.getOrBuild().authenticate(authentication)).tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("CLIENT_NAME")...;
    }

}
```

Resource server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }
}
```

So far so good. When the custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` comes into action I start to have problems, though. Since the `EnableResourceServer`-annotated bean creates a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with `Order(3)` it gets executed on every request first, the user is successfully authenticated/authorized, but my custom logic in my `WebSecurityConfiguration` is not executed. On the other hand if i set `WebSecurityConfiguration` to have an `Order(2)` or less, the custom `access` rules are executed, but it always says they're coming from an anonymous user (since the rules in the bean created by `@EnableResourceServer` are not executed).

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/path/**")
        .access("@security.hasPermission(authentication, 'SOME', 'VALUE')");

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Just as a side note, the `@security` reference in the `access` rules is just a simple named Spring bean:

```
@Component("security")
public class SecurityService {
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, String param, String anotherParam) { ... }
}
```

I have integration tests that validate the custom access rules in `WebSecurityConfiguration` and they work (since I skip the authentication there). I'd like to be able to use the resource server just for authentication and then my custom http security for authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to use oauth2, and you first get a token and use it in your API (using `Authorization Bearer [TOKEN]`) you need to change your logic a bit in order to create custom expressions.

First of all, if you use spring boot 1.5+, please consider adding the following property to your application.properties file: `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3` ([1.5 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes#oauth-2-resource-filter))

Now in order to create custom filters you need to understand some components.

By default spring provide the following interface `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` in order to handle security expressions and the implementation that is used is `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`. Usually you will override it with `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` for oauth2 but lets create a custom one with our own implementation.

This class use the interface `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations` that is implemented by `SecurityExpressionRoot` to parse expressions.

First, we need to create a custom `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations`. at the bottom of it you can find `// custom logic methods` stating the start of the custom logic (on top of it are spring's implementation to keep compatibility with their expressions):

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    // Based on MethodSecurityExpressionRoot (class is package private in spring)
    private Object filterObject;
    private Object returnObject;
    private Object target;

    CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication a) {
        super(a);
    }

    public void setFilterObject(Object filterObject) {
        this.filterObject = filterObject;
    }

    public Object getFilterObject() {
        return filterObject;
    }

    public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject) {
        this.returnObject = returnObject;
    }

    public Object getReturnObject() {
        return returnObject;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the "this" property for use in expressions. Typically this will be
     * the "this" property of the {@code JoinPoint} representing the method
     * invocation which is being protected.
     *
     * @param target
     *            the target object on which the method in is being invoked.
     */
    void setThis(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public Object getThis() {
        return target;
    }

    // custom logic methods
    public boolean securityHasPermission(String param, String anotherParam) {
        /* custom logic here */
    }
```

Next, we need to set it as our root in a custom `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`:

```
public class CustomOAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    private final AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication,
            MethodInvocation invocation) {
        final CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setThis(invocation.getThis());
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());

        return root;
    }

}
```

Next, we need to set it as the default `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`. We can do that by extending `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`. in that file we define a new `@Bean` for our custom `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and overriding `createExpressionHandler()` in order to set it as default:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class Oauth2GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return methodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        return new CustomOAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
```

Now in your controllers you can add `@PreAuthorize("securityHasPermission('SOME', 'VALUE')")` to trigger your custom logic

Your custom logic should be triggered in `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot` and you can access `authentication` variable as it is already injected into the class when its initialized. you can also pass more parameters/beans when setting it in `CustomOAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`.

Comment: PreAuth is completely different from OAuth though, is it not? Actually curious. I was on preAuth and was told to switch it to oauth since the token i was utilizing was not pre-authenticated before it hits my application, and even if you are calling out for an authenticated token after receiving non-authenticated tokens, the utilization is still not technically pre-auth, from what i was told.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things in the above code, first, you should assign the client with some authorities.

here some code doing that:

in OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig you should change this

```
clients.inMemory().withClient("CLIENT_NAME").authorities("ADMIN")....;
```

and in the matcher you should do

```
 http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/path/**")
    .hasAuthority("ADMIN");
```

or you can add annotation for the secure method/controller

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this generating the `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` instance as a bean.

Instead do that:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
             return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

        ....
}
```

do this:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
             return getOAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

        @Bean
        public OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler getOAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
             return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

        ....
}
```

Hope this'll others !